# How can I detect blocks of text from scanned document images

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, convolution, opencv, image-preprocessing

**ORIGINAL IMAGE:**

[image]

**GOAL:**

[image]

I want to separate texts into individual paragraphs by placing bounding boxes over them (as shown above).

I tried it do this via traditional computer vision approach using opencv.

1. I plotted character level bounding box
2. Next, I gray-scaled the image, binarized it.
3. Applied dilation
4. And finally placed bbox over the dilated image.

This is what I get:

[image]

```
> #Morphological Transformation

kernel = np.ones((3,4),np.int8)

dilation = cv2.dilate(im_bw, kernel)

cv2.imwrite('dilated.png', dilation)
```

## Plotting rectangular box

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im_bw, 127,255,0)
image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )

for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if rect[2] < 50 or rect[3] < 50 : continue

    print (cv2.contourArea(c))
    x,y,w,h = rect
    cv2.rectangle(im_new,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imwrite('sample_res_inner.jpg',im_new)
```

Since the image is scanned image plus the line-spaces between them are small I couldn't able to segment them based on paragraphs.

How can I get my desired result?

Comment: May you post the original image without any processing?

Comment: @Edmund It's done now.

Comment: I think you should refer to the following link: [getting-paragraph-sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249273/how-to-detect-paragraphs-in-a-text-document-image-for-a-non-consistent-text-stru)

Comment: It is a year old post.. wondering if the solution was found. Can you post here please

Answer (score 3):

There are two options :

1. Scan the images with a higher DPI. This should accentuate vertical separation between paragraphs.
2. Train a Deep learning model for Text Detection in scene. Examples : https://github.com/qjadud1994/CRNN-Keras and https://github.com/mvoelk/ssd_detectors

Comment: Well, the above mentioned methods are scene text detectors. It will detect the texts word by word. It doesn't perform segmentation by paragraphs which is want.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIs1SUH_3Lw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Video mentioned above is a demo of model that extends the approach to paragraphs.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03286  . It starts with word boundaries and trains an "attention" layer to identify paragraph boundaries.

Comment: I just want to detect paragraphs and i don't want to recognize it now. Will this method help to detect the paragraphs or group of text that lies together as mentioned under GOAL section. If so, can u please provide the implementation of this paper

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Tesseract (and its Python wrapper/interface: [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/))?  I don't guarantee that it will solve your problems entirely, but it offers bounding box and OCR features.

On [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage) Tesseract site it lists possible page segmentation modes that you could play around with.

There is also [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality) page that provides some quality improvement suggestions.

There are many questions/answers on Stack Overflow about specific usage cases.  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52102891/9987623) answer, for example, there is a recommendation to use OSM mode to detect multiple columns.

And there is this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925602/9987623) that offers a way to break text into paragraphs.